# Как прописать универсальные пути в JS при Fetch-запросах?

Tags: javascript, openserver, fetch

Суть в следующем. Загрузил сайт на хостинг. Во время загрузки при первом же fetch-запросе js не находит путь до handle.php, из-за чего весь сайт отображается неправильно.

Но даже если я изменю пути, то с аналогичными проблемами я столкнусь при работе в эмуляторе на Open Server. Как бы я не изменил пути в проекте для хостинга, в Open Server всё равно всё сломается и не будет работать.

Так примерно выглядит запрос (это часть кода):

```
fetch('/Jumpers/handle.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
```

Адрес на хостинге должен быть такой: http://название сайта/handle.php

На деле же, когда заходишь на сайт, то он пытается зайти по неправильному адресу (добавляет /Jumpers), и получается ошибка:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) /Jumpers/handle.php:1

Если из fetch-запроса убрать /Jumpers, то сломается работа в эмуляторе:

> POST http://jumpers/handle.php 404 (Not Found)

В итоге получается замкнутый круг, из которого не выбраться.

Мне подсказали, что нужно использовать универсальные пути, только для js как это сделать?

Я попробовал поставить точку, вместо /Jumpers/handle.php написал ./handle.php, но это не помогло. Пишет ошибку:

> POST http://название сайта/handle.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 это ошибка в самом файле

Comment: @InDevX Файл, как файл. В эмуляторе работает.`<?php
require ('vendor/autoload.php');
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);

if ($request['method'] == 'reg')
    // регистрация нового юзера
{`

Comment: И что? Там работает, там не работает... Вы думаете раз в одном месте работает, значит так везде будет? Добавьте вывод ошибок в файле и в нетворке смотрите что пишет

Comment: @InDevX как это сделать?

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин PHP  ```try...catch``` :https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php

Comment: @Locker но у меня же есть try catch!

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин Какая у вас структура файлов? Логируете ли Вы ошибку?

Comment: Нашел подобную проблему: https://bit.ly/31WlkNu

Comment: @Locker Создал отдельную тему по ошибке 500: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267471/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-500-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-try-catch