# Ошибка 500 на хостинге с пустым исключением try catch

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-500

Залил сайт на хостинг. При заходе сразу же консоль выводит ошибку:

> POST http://название сайта/handle.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Как понять, что именно ему не нравится?

Фрагмент кода fetch-запроса:

```
fetch('./handle.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then((data)=>{

        console.log(data);
// дальше еще есть код
```

Начало файла handle.php с примером типичного взятия $request['method']:

```
<?php
require ('vendor/autoload.php');
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);

if ($request['method'] == 'reg')
    // регистрация нового юзера
{
    try {


  $objReg = new \Jumpers\Reg($request['login'], $request['pass'], $request['pass2'], $request['email']);
    $check = $objReg->checkInputs();
        if (is_array($check) && !empty($check)) {
        echo json_encode($check);
        exit();
}

    $login = $objReg->createUser();
    $sendResult = $objReg->sendEmail();
    $objUsers = new \Jumpers\Users($login);
    $userId = $objUsers->getUserId();
    $objStat = new \Jumpers\Stat();
    $objStat->setUserId($userId);
    $objStat->createStatRow();
    $objUsers->setUserOnline();
    if ($request['remember']) {
        setcookie('logged', $login, time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, '/');
    } else {
        setcookie('logged', $login, 0, '/');
    }
    echo json_encode(['login' => $login, 'sendResult' => $sendResult]);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
}
elseif ($request['method'] == 'exit')
// и так далее
```

Несколько скриншотов с тем, что у меня происходит в консоли:
[image: Интересует именно эта ошибка, обведенная квадратом, остальное не смотрите]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Пустое исключение]

Извините за сумбур, не совсем понимаю, как ещё можно это показать.

Comment: если статус 500, то надо смотреть в лог ошибок на сервере. там написано, в чём проблема

Comment: Покажите иерархию Ваших файлов. Логирование ошибок: https://itfb.com.ua/gde-php-hranit-logi-oshibok-error-log/

Comment: 1. Ответы на сетевые ошибки надо смотреть на вкладке network. 2. Сервер бери и дебажь. 3. А в fetch надо статус проверять.